# How should I check out a newly added project from git repository?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I am new to Git hub/git.

Till Now:

I am using egit i.e eclipse's plugin for Git.Cloned remote repository successfully and all the existing files are available in local.
I can also see incoming changes on the existing projects that I checked out when I synchronize in eclipse.

Problem:

Now a new project has been added in the same repository.I can see the new project when I login in Git hub online. But there are no incoming changes in the eclipse.

So,what should I do to check out the newly added project from eclipse's egit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new project is in the same branch your working directory uses than the simple pull should bring you the new project. If the new project is added to a new branch then you should checkout that branch.